# MacOS cmd+"+" and/or cmd+"=" not zooming safari, chrome, preview,

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to figure out why <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> works only in VS Code...

Chrome, Safari, Preview,... all applications report that <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> is zoom in. Sure. It does not work. I have Slovak keyboard where <kbd>+</kbd> second key in second row (with <kbd>shift</kbd>I type "1" without I type <kbd>+</kbd>) the <kbd>=</kbd> is right behind the zero (0) key (% with <kbd>shift</kbd>. = without <kbd>shift</kbd>).

In both Safari and Chrome <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is switching to first tab. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> does nothing. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>é</kbd> (0 with <kbd>shift</kbd>) is restoring to "Actual size".

But when I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>,  <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> neither of them work on Slovak keyboard. On Slovak keyboard only <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> works correctly.

On English keyboard it works with the two keys right before the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key.

What I have tried:

- Restoring System -> KeyBoard -> shortcuts to defaults
- Reading apple docs for keyboard shortcuts but it only refers to "Accessibility" screen zoom, and not window content zoom.
- Googling for about and hour.

keyboard layout 1

[image: keyboard layout]

keyboard layout 2

[image: keyboard layout 2]

Comment: Try cmd-option-+  and cmd-option--

Comment: I have described in question that it did not work. (Works only in accessibility it's allowed. but it's different king of  zoom, it zooms the screen like magnifier... and not the document or webpage, or image...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved thanks to the Apple community. In the Slovak layout there is no <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> since <kbd>cmd</kbd> modifies like <kbd>shift</kbd>. So when I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>, the <kbd>+</kbd> key becomes <kbd>1</kbd> like when I press <kbd>shift</kbd>. So I needed to create a custom shortcut for the application to be able to zoom in using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: Could you share what's the exact string to use for a custom app shortcut?

Comment: @BorekBernard I am sorry, I don´t remember it. I would check it out, but I sold my MacBook.